# Accessing specific data from a cURL response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl, simplexml

If anyone can help here it would be very much appreciated. I have created a function which sends a cURL request and saves the response. For a specific request I have received the following response. Which when I use print_r gives...

A string:
2017-08-25T09:56:29.172ZSuccess949E949_INTL_API_17934825_R1TESTUSB_WHITETESTUSB_BLACK

And some XML:

```
<getitemresponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<timestamp>2017-08-25T09:56:29.172Z</timestamp>
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>949</version>
<build>E949_INTL_API_17934825_R1</build>
<item>
<variations>
  <variation>
    <sku>TESTUSB_WHITE</sku>
  </variation>
  <variation>
    <sku>TESTUSB_BLACK</sku>
  </variation>
</variations>
</item>
</getitemresponse>
```

My question is how do I access the values at the sku elements.

I have tried to convert the response to a \SimpleXmlElement and used print_r which gives.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Timestamp] => 2017-08-25T10:09:59.016Z
    [Ack] => Success
    [Version] => 949
    [Build] => E949_INTL_API_17934825_R1
    [Item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Variations] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Variation] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [SKU] => TESTUSB_WHITE
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [SKU] => TESTUSB_BLACK
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And again I don't know how to access SKU here. Any help would be very much appreciated thanks for reading. Also if you have a different approach all together I would also be happy to hear that. Can I access SKU directly from the string response?

Comment: You could use an xpath query.  From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Thank you would you recommend, using xpath or DOMXpath.

Comment: Please check my answer below, its now as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use XPath to access this node-values:

```
$xml = new \SimpleXmlElement($xmlAsString);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ebay', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$skuNodes = $xml->xpath('//ebay:sku'); // return all sku elements, everywhere in the document
```

now you can loop through them or do what ever you want

```
foreach($skuNodes as $_ => $node)
    echo "<span>".htmlentities($node)."</span>";
```

fiddle: http://codepad.org/tzSvo4yV

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. This seems to be on the right track, but I get a blank array returned for this. It still doesn't seem to be able to find SKU in the objects.

Comment: it's beacuse of the xml namespace. I will update my answer in a second

Comment: Hello Joshua, thank you for all you help. I will have a play with this as I am still getting the blank array. It think this may be because cURL returns a special type of string so its not working exactly the same. You have helped massively thank you.

Comment: Got it. It because SKU is capital letters in my object. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** Try this..

```
$xmlArray = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($xmlArray);
$xmlFormated = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Now, you can loop through array to find all sku elements.

```
foreach($xmlFormated['item']['variations']['variation'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value['sku'];
}
```

Comment: the question was _how do I access the values at the sku elements._ not _how can I convert xml to json_ or _how can I convert xml to a php object_

Comment: Updated answer to satisfy OP's need.

Comment: Thank you Dhruvil